# FLOW3: initialization of multi databases

Tags: php, database, doctrine, typo3-flow

I want to prepare two database connection, because in the first one are the stuff for the Website (e. g. Blogs, posts, etc.) and in the other one are the account data.
The account data is in a other database, because it's my authentication database with permissions for FTP, SSH, IMAP etc.

The password is hashed with Mysql function ENCRYPT. So I must create a new Cryptography, Provider and Token. I don't want to change the structure of my database.

(It's FLOW3 Version 1.1beta2)

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple:

I must prepate a seperate database in my mysql database. It isn't the right solution but it is a possibility.
[create-server (dev.mysql.com)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-server.html)